# Google Sheets conditional based on dropdown selection value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheet with a cell (let's say its `M4`) that is a dropdown list that I created by:

1. Selecting the cell
2. Selecting `Data` >> `Data validation` >> `Criteria` >> `List of items`
3. Providing a comma-delimited list of values (`RED,BLUE,GREEN`)
4. Selecting **Save**

I am know trying to write a conditional formula for *another* cell (let's say its `N4`) based on the value selected of this `M4` cell:

- if `M4` is `RED` then I want the value of `N4` to be 35
- else I want `N4` to be 25

So I select `N4` enter `=if(M4=='RED',35,25)` and click **Enter**.

I get `#ERROR` as the `N4` value and when I mouseover it I see:

```
Error

Formula parse error.
```

**Where am I going awry?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula in N4 to:

```
=if(M4="RED",35,25)
```

Spreadsheets don't differentiate between assignment and comparison so everything only needs a single equals, plus strings require double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, oh mighty God ofBiscuits!